# Computer randomly shuts off

Tags: crash

After playing games for random amounts of time, my PC randomly shuts off. I say random because this could happen every 15 minutes while playing, and sometimes not at all over the course of several hours. No blue screen, no warning of overheating(it's not overheating as I've checked the temps while playing games), nothing. The PC just shuts off for about 1.5 seconds, then automatically turns back on. I have tried reseating every part, unplugging every unnecessary fan, I even unplugged extra hard drives and DVD drives. I took out each stick of RAM, and placed each one in a separate slot individually, and it still happened. There is no problem with it when it starts back up, it starts up as if nothing had happened, and I'm able to play games fine instantly afterwards. I am not overclocking anything, I actually brought my processor back from 2.8gz to 2.3ghz when this began happening, and it still happens. I have no idea what's causing this, it has only begun happening since I have moved to a new house. The tricky bit is, I can browse the internet/youtube all day long with no problems. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I should also add that I have reformatted Windows after this happened several times, and the problem still persists.

Here is my setup:

1. Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600)
   (9600.winblue_gdr.131030-1505)
2. Motherboard: Gigabyte Z68P-DS3
3. BIOS: Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG
4. Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU
   @ 2.80GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
5. Memory: 16384MB RAM
6. GPU: EVGA 980GTX
7. PSU: CORSAIR HX Series HX750 750W ATX12V 2.3 / EPS12V 2.91

Comment: It seems like you've done extensive testing on the innards of your computer for problems. Have you tried a different outlet in your new house?

Comment: I have tried a few different outlets via extension cord, though I'm no electrical expert so I'm not sure how the house is wired.

Comment: If it works all day non gaming then I would suspect either the graphical card, or the higher power draw from the PSU.  Do you have spares which you can swap in for either of these?  Do you have a 'smart extension caord' which can show you voltage drops ?

Comment: Try running http://www.playtool.com/pages/prime95/prime95.html for some hours and see if it causes crashing as well. Have you checked if there is anything suspicious on logs at the time of the crash?

Comment: I'm not sure what I should check @Madoc, any tips?

Also, I switched back to my old GPU(EVGA 670 GTX) and I'm going to see how it goes Hennes.

Thanks for the responses guys.

Comment: You could get a UPS (Uninterrupted Power Supply) and plug everything into it to protect your equipment. If it is power from the house is causing this, the UPS will cycle, and your PC will stay on. In that case, you know the house electrical will need to be looked at. Continuing as it is, you risk damaging equipment.

Comment: Not sure if Win 8 has similar logs as Win 7, but in Event Viewer check Windows logs. Are there anything marked as Critical or Error close to time of crash?

Comment: Leaning towards a bad PSU as well.

Comment: I ran with my old video card for several hours with no crashes, so I guess it's the 980 that's bad.